How to increase Client assertion time range in deploying azure biceps from DevOpsPipeline?
I have a big script which launching serval biceps files to set up my application infrastruture. I am running it in a devops pipeline.
My problem is that after 10 min, I have this error while my script is launching a new biceps file :

Client assertion is not within its valid time range. Current time: 2024-05-09T12:53:26.4180283Z, assertion valid from 2024-05-09T12:37:55.0000000Z, expiry time of assertion 2024-05-09T12:47:54.0000000Z

This script is execute using a pipeline :
trigger:


 - develop

pool:   vmImage: "windows-latest" variables:   BuildNumber: $(Build.BuildNumber)

steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Deploy App Environment"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "Dev-AzureSubscription"
      scriptType: "ps"
      scriptLocation: scriptPath
      scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/mainBuildScirpt.ps1
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

Dev-AzureSubscription have been using a federated token to connect to Azure via an Azure Application.
I have no idea how and where I can increase or at least control this 10 min timeout cofiguration for this connection.
Does someone have any ideas ?

Hi, can the solution that add commands that (implicitly) request an access token to the beginning of your script help with the issue?

You can also try to create a new service connection and check if the same issue happens.

I found the problem, my security team change the token max time from 24h to 15 min so my script was too long.
I tried many way to refresh the token inside the azure CLI but didn't success. The only way that i found was to split my script into smaller script to make that the last biceps call from each script was lower than 15 min after the beggining.
trigger:
  - develop

parameters:
- name: AzureConnectedService
  type: string
  default: 'Dev-AzureSubscription'

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"
variables:
  BuildNumber: $(Build.BuildNumber)

steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Deploy KeyVault"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.AzureConnectedService}}
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
      scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/mainBuildScirptKeyVault.ps1'
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useGlobalConfig: true
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Deploy SQL Database"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.AzureConnectedService}}
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
      scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/mainBuildScirptSQLServer.ps1'
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useGlobalConfig: true
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

---etc


Splitting the script into smaller script is a good idea! Thanks for sharing the solution. This may benefit others who met the same error!

According to this document Troubleshoot an Azure Resource Manager workload identity service connection, when you get the error message "Client assertion is not within its valid time range",

If the error happens after approximately 1 hour, use a service connection with Workload identity federation and a Managed Identity instead. Managed Identity tokens have a lifetime of around 24 hours.
If the error happens before 1 hour but after 10 minutes, move commands that (implicitly) request an access token to e.g. access Azure storage to the beginning of your script. The access token will be cached for subsequent commands.

In your case, the error happens after 10 minutes, so you can try to add commands that (implicitly) request an access token to the beginning of your script.
